# What is the difference between mixins and generics?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, mixins, django-generic-views

I'm learning about the Django Rest Framework. And there are two concepts that from my point of view are almost the same, and they are used in different scenarios.

`rest_framework mixins` I think that they are used when we use viewsets.
And `rest_framework generics` are used with APIViews.

What is the difference between these two components?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between Generics, Views, Viewsets and Mixins in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48506898/what-are-the-differences-between-generics-views-viewsets-and-mixins-in-django)

Comment: If you ever have the time, I strongly suggest going through [this comprehensive django CBV guide](https://spapas.github.io/2018/03/19/comprehensive-django-cbv-guide/) - it's long, but well worth reading, it should clarify all doubts related to mixins and what not.

Answer (score 6):

The `generics` and `mixin` modules are indeed different, yet they are inter-related.

Django Rest Framework (DRF) separates ReSTful API / HTTP verb behaviour from Django model operations and organises a set of abstract/base classes for each. The ReSTful functionality is in `APIView`, `GenericAPIView` and `ViewSetMixin`. The Model related operations are implemented in the `mixin` module.

DRF then makes use of Python's multiple inheritance, and the "mixin" pattern, to combine these together into higher-level classes that are both useable and extensible.

The generic views and the concrete `ModelViewSet` both inherit from `APIView` in addition to composing functionality via the `mixin` classes.

---

*Though not related to the question, the following observation about ViewSets may be helpful...*

The following is the intro to ViewSets on the DRF site that might make things seem more complicated than they really are...

> A ViewSet class is **simply a type of class-based View, that does not provide any method handlers** such as .get() or .post(), and instead provides actions such as .list() and .create().
>
> The method handlers for a ViewSet are only bound to the corresponding actions at the point of finalizing the view, using the .as_view() method.

Rather than inheriting the `ViewSet` directly, in many cases, it will make the most sense to inherit a `ModelViewSet` and combine it with a `DefaultRouter`. The `ModelViewSet` obtains the method handlers via the various `mixin` classes, and the `DefaultRouter` provides the 'action' function mapping.

In combination, all the basic REST actions can be performed on a given Model, with very little code.