# Generic Views vs APIView vs Viewsets, vs ModelViewsets

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I just started learning Django Rest Framework and I get to now about 4 concepts APIView, Viewsets, Modelviewsets, GenericView. What is the difference between them and which of them is more efficient to use in the development of rest APIs and why?

Comment: Btw you can accept my answer if it was helpful.

Answer (score 16):

There is no standard but you can start with this simple strategy:

1. Several actions in one class and basic CRUD ---> [Viewset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#viewsets) (`ModelViewSet` and `ReadOnlyModelViewSet` are most useful)
2. Specific action on a model class ---> [Generic Views](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/) (`RetrieveModelMixin`, `ListAPIView`, `UpdateModelMixin`, `DestroyModelMixin`, `CreateModelMixin`)
3. If you want to write all `create`, `update`, ... methods yourself you can use `APIView` and write them in your `get`, `post`, `put`, ... methods (Difference between `APIView` & `GenericAPIView` is only you cant use some builtin methods in your class , like `queryset`, `serializer_class`, ... )
4. And if you want to write everything from scratch you can write your apis in `function base`

- Most of the times you have to write you apis with Generic Views & If you learn all of the Generic APIView best practices, it has so much power and your will be so clean, readable and scalable
- Buy if you have simple Models you can use Viewset

> I use GenericAPIView in normal APIs & use APIView in the custom ones (like most of APIs in Admin Panel)

Comment: There are some cases in which we have to make relations between models for that purpose we have to define our own urls and write our on function I have done this in Viewsets is this same in generic views to write my own functions?

Comment: @DavidGardner What you need to know is that `Viewset` helps us register routes better. When you use `GenericView` and need to write custom functions, how do these functions register routes need to be considered.

Comment: The name GenericAPIView is so confusing. It suggests that one should go for APIView in most cases and only go for GenericAPIView to impplement something highly customized, whereas the opposite is the case (at least this is how I understand this reply).